# How to determine if these summations converge or diverge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

> [image: |]

The answer is apparently

> D

, but I'm not sure how to get it. I tried plugging in numbers and seeing where it got me, but I couldn't get any closer to solving the answer. I thought the correct answer was

> C

, but it wasn't. How are you supposed to solve it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of text or equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: I agree that plugging in numbers isn't a helpful way to approach these problems. The [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) is a perfect tool for these infinite series.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Sorry but I don't know how to use MathJax. [This is the test that it's based off of though.](https://www.rickardsinvitational.org/2017Tests/Precalculus%20Indiv%20Test.pdf). It's question 4.

Comment: Here's a *MathJax* tutorial:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference